# Integration testing authorized endpoints with already specified authentication schemes

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, integration-testing, .net-6.0

I am trying to set up integration tests for my ASP.NET Web API with authorized endpoints.

I have followed the documentation from Microsoft to add mock authentication to the integration tests to allow the test client to access the authorized endpoints. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

E.g.

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Test")
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    });
}
```

This works fine if you are using default authentication schemes that you can change on the startup of your integration tests to use the test scheme. But, my authorized endpoints are using specified `AuthenticationSchemes` so the test scheme will never be authorized for the endpoint. E.g.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme1,Scheme2")]
public class AppVersionController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

I can get around this issue by specifying an environment variable when testing, checking this and dynamically adding the test scheme to the authorized endpoint. Yet, this adds a lot of test-specific logic to the app, which isn't nice to have in the main project.

This would work:

```
// Test scheme added dynamically from an environment variable to get the below result
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme1,Scheme2,Test")]
public class AppVersionController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

I get this done by creating a custom attribute that looks basically like this:

```
public class AuthorizeAll : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeAll()
    {
        var authenticationSchemes = "Scheme1,Scheme2";
        if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Testing")
        {
            authenticationSchemes += ",Test";
        }
        AuthenticationSchemes = authenticationSchemes;
    }
}
```

I just don't like how we will have to continue to maintain this test authentication scheme in the application layer as well as the security concerns with this approach.

### Questions

What is the best way to authorize endpoints for .NET integration tests when specific authentication schemes are set?

Is it good practice to check environment variables in the app when unit testing to run specific logic that the tests need to work?

The main authentication scheme used at the moment is using JWTs, so is there a better way to mock JWTs for the tests?

Comment: Whats the problem of creating httpclient which implements those schemes? In my experience in integration testing I've never needed any test schemes, just passed headers with credentials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways you can mock authentication (triggered from authorization policy). Depends on your app setup, you might choose what's the "best" for you.

**1. Use default policy**

When you use `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Scheme1,Scheme2")]` on an action/controller, the default authorization policy is combined before evaluation. In your test setup, you can combine an empty policy with *Test* scheme with the default policy from the actual code to make sure your *Test* scheme always runs.

```cs
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
    {
        opt.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Test")
            .Combine(opt.DefaultPolicy)
            .Build();
    });
});
```

The above code will authenticate the request using three policies: *Scheme1*, *Scheme2* and *Test*. This won't work for you if you also have `[Authorize(Policy = "Policy1")]`.

**2. Use a custom policy evaluator**

ASP.NET Core evaluates authorization policy in a service of type `IPolicyEvaluator`. You can override this service in your test to always authenticate the request using a specific scheme. You can also do it per request.

```cs
class TestPolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
{
    private readonly PolicyEvaluator _innerEvaluator;

    public TestPolicyEvaluator(PolicyEvaluator innerEvaluator)
    {
        _innerEvaluator = innerEvaluator;
    }

    public Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, 
        HttpContext context)
    {
        var combinedPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Test")
            .Combine(policy)
            .Build();

        return _innerEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(combinedPolicy, context);
    }

    public Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy,
        AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object? resource)
    {
        return _innerEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(policy, authenticationResult,
            context, resource);
    }
}
```

Then add this to your test setup:

```cs
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.AddTransient<IPolicyEvaluator>(serviceProvider => new TestPolicyEvaluator(
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<PolicyEvaluator>(serviceProvider)));
});
```

This works similarly as the default policy solution, and should work for all policy evaluation scenarios.

**3. Use custom security token validation**

You can also customize how your JWT token is validated. You can tweak your token validation parameters to allow a test-specific JWT token. Alternatively, you can also use a customized token validator.

```cs
class TestJwtSecurityTokenHandler : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _innerHandler = new();

    public bool CanValidateToken => _innerHandler.CanValidateToken;

    public int MaximumTokenSizeInBytes
    {
        get => _innerHandler.MaximumTokenSizeInBytes;
        set => _innerHandler.MaximumTokenSizeInBytes = value;
    }

    public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken) => true;

    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, 
        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters,
        out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {
        validatedToken = new JwtSecurityToken();
        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity("Test"));
    }
}
```

Assuming you have a JWT scheme called *Scheme1*, you can configure it in your test setup:

```cs
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>("Scheme1", opt =>
    {
        // Tweak parameters
        opt.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;
                        
        // Or, fully override token validator
        opt.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
        opt.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new TestJwtSecurityTokenHandler());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the options. The first one looks like what I want, but still can't get it working even with your example even though I don't authorize with any policy like `[Authorize(Policy = "Policy1")]` the second option does work perfectly for me though.

Answer (score -1):

Answering your questions:

1. Enrich your `HttpClient` with auth headers in tests. Use it.
2. **NO**
3. Look at (1)

Microsoft has [good explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0) how to do integration testing of *ASP.NET Core* projects. Usually you start your service on `[OneTimeSetUp]` and shutdown on `[OneTimeTearDown]`, in tests you can interact with it using simple `HttpClient`, the **same way your clients do it**.

For example:

```
[Fact]
public async Task HelloWorldTest()
{
    //your MyApp.Web.Program
    var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>() 
        .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            // here you can mock some external dependencies of your service, such as logging or database
        });

    //your http client to connect, you can tweak headers here
    using var client = application.CreateClient();
}
```

This way it will be full-blown service started as it would in stage except things you tweak in container (mocks/stubs/etc).

Comment: The link you provided from Microsoft shows to mock the authentication which is what has been done in my example see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#mock-authentication. I assume you are just saying to do the auth call first and actually use an authenticated JWT to do the rest of the integration tests?

Comment: Yeah, make full cycle using JWT (probably just wrap it up into set of helpers if you are going to use it much). That's what I would do at least, because for integration/unit tests I often prioritize maximum coverage and by mocking something - you losing coverage. Which can contain a bug, for example some memory leaks in JWT or who knows what. With near 100% coverage the only thing which can go wrong is your host environment. I use mock, but mostly for unit tests.